I can't make in my xv6. I just edited proc.h and proc.c, but 'inb' function which is in x86.h didn't declared well
I'm in Operating System class and doing homework with xv6.
My job was to make MLFQ scheduler so i was editing proc.h and types.h.
But when i try to make my xv6,error like this happens.
root@123:/OS/xv6-public# make
gcc -fno-pic -static -fno-builtin -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -Wall -MD -ggdb -m32 -Werror -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -no-pie   -c -o console.o console.c
In file included from console.c:16:
x86.h:4:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'inb'
    4 | inb(ushort port)
      | ^~~
console.c: In function 'cgaputc':
console.c:138:9: error: implicit declaration of function 'inb' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  138 |   pos = inb(CRTPORT+1) << 8;
      |         ^~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [<builtin>: console.o] Error 1

In my opinion, i think there is some problem with type 'uchar' so the function 'inb' is not declared well.....
But i NEVER EDITED types.h, and x86.h..................
//x86.h

// Routines to let C code use special x86 instructions.

static inline uchar
inb(ushort port)
{
  uchar data;

  asm volatile("in %1,%0" : "=a" (data) : "d" (port));
  return data;
}


//types.h
typedef unsigned int   uint;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned char  uchar;
typedef uint pde_t;

//console.c
// Cursor position: col + 80*row.
  outb(CRTPORT, 14);
  pos = inb(CRTPORT+1) << 8;
  outb(CRTPORT, 15);
  pos |= inb(CRTPORT+1);

This is what i edited.
//proc.h
struct proc {
  uint sz;                     // Size of process memory (bytes)
  pde_t* pgdir;                // Page table
  char *kstack;                // Bottom of kernel stack for this process
  enum procstate state;        // Process state
  int pid;                     // Process ID
  struct proc *parent;         // Parent process
  struct trapframe *tf;        // Trap frame for current syscall
  struct context *context;     // swtch() here to run process
  void *chan;                  // If non-zero, sleeping on chan
  int killed;                  // If non-zero, have been killed
  struct file *ofile[NOFILE];  // Open files
  struct inode *cwd;           // Current directory
  char name[16];               // Process name (debugging)

  //project02
  int level;
  int priority;
  int proc_tick;
};

// Process memory is laid out contiguously, low addresses first:
//   text
//   original data and bss
//   fixed-size stack
//   expandable heap


// project 02
struct mlfq {
  int limit;
  struct proc* procs[NPROC];
  struct proc* prev;
  int prev_index;
}

// proc.c

void
scheduler(void)
{
  struct proc *p;
  struct cpu *c = mycpu();
  c->proc = 0;

  struct proc *highest_level;
  struct proc *lowest_pid;
  struct proc *highest_priority;
  int global_tick = 0;
  
  acquire(&mlfqlock);
  for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    mlfq[i].limit = 2*i+2;
    mlfq[i].prev=0;
    mlfq[i].prev_index=-1;
  }
  mlfq[4].limit = 1000;
  mlfq[4].prev = 0;
  mlfq[4].prev_index = 0;
  release(&mlfqlock);

  
  for(;;){
    // Enable interrupts on this processor.
    sti();

    // Loop over process table looking for process to run.
    acquire(&ptable.lock);

    for(p = ptabel.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
      if(p!=0){
        hightest level = p;
        highest_priority = p;
        lowest_pid = p;
        break;
      }
    }

    for(p = ptabel.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
      if(proc_check(p) == -1) continue;
      if(p->level > highest_level->level) highest_level=p;
      if(p->priority > highest_priority->priority) highest_priority=p;
      if(p->pid < lowest_pid) lowest_pid=p;
    }

    if(highest_level->level < 3){
      p = highest_level;
    }
    else if(highest_level->level == 3){
      p = highest_priority;
    }
    else if(highest_level->level ==4){
      p = lowest_pid;
    }

    if(proc_check(mlfq[p->level].prev) == 0){
      p = mlfq[p->level].prev;
    }
    else if (p->level == 0 || p->level == 1 || p->level == 2){
      p= mlfq[p->level].procs[(mlfq[p->level].prev_index+1) % NPROC];
    }


    // Switch to chosen process.  It is the process's job
    // to release ptable.lock and then reacquire it
    // before jumping back to us.
    c->proc = p;
    switchuvm(p);
    p->state = RUNNING;

    swtch(&(c->scheduler), p->context);
    switchkvm();

    // Process is done running for now.
    // It should have changed its p->state before coming back.
    c->proc = 0;

    if(p->level !=4){
      acquire(&mlfqlock);
      global_tick++;
      release(&mlfqlock);
      p->prock_tick++;
    }

    mlfq[p->level].prev = p;
    for(int i = 0; i<NPROC; i++){
      if(mlfq[p->level].procs[i] == p){
        mlfq[p->level].prev_index = i
        break;
      }
    }

    if(p->proc_tick >= mlfq[p->level].limit){
      if(p->level == 0){
        if(p->pid % 2 == 1) proc_changelevel(1, p);
        else proc_changelevel(2,p);
      }
      else if(p->level == 1 || p->level == 2){
        proc_changelevel(3,p);
      }
      else if(p->level == 3){
        if(p->priority > 0) p->priority--;
        p->proc_tick = 0;
      }
    }
    
    release(&ptable.lock);

  }
}



//proc.c
int
proc_insertqueue(int level, struct proc* p)
{
  if(level<0 || levle >4){
    cprintf("out of level range\n");
    return -1;
  }
  for(int = 0; i< NPROC; i++){
    if(mlfq[level].procs[i] == 0){
      mlfq[p->level].prev=0;
      p->level = level;
      p->proc_tick=0;
      mlfq[level].procs[i]=p;
      return 0;
    }
  }
  cprintf("out of space in that level\n");
  return -1;
}


int
proc_delqueue(struct proc* p)
{
  int level = p->level;
  if(level < 0 || level > 4){
    cprintf("out of level range\n");
    return -1;
  }
  if(empty_mlfq(level)){
    return -1;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < NPROC; i++){
    if(mlfq[level].procs[i] == p){
      mlfq[level].procs[i] = 0;
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

int
proc_changelevel(int level, sturct proc* p)
{
  if(proc_delqueue(p)==-1){
    cprintf("no such process\n");
    return -1;
  }
  return proc_insertqueue(level, p);
}


int
level_changeL0(void)
{
  struct proc* p;
  for(p = ptable.proc; p< &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++){
    if(p==0) continue;
    if(p->level == 0){
      p->proc_tick = 0;
    }
    else proc_changelevel(0,p);
  }
  return 0;
}

int
proc_check(struct proc* p)
{
  if(p==0 || p->state != RUNNABLE || p->proc_tick >= mlfq[p->level].limit){
    return -1;
  }
  else return 0;
}

int
mlfq_empty(int level){
  int num=0;
  for(int i=0; i<NPROC; i++){
    if(mlfq[level].procs[i] != 0){
      num++;
    }
  }
  if (num ==0) return 0;
  else return -1;
}

I literally have no idea about what caused this whole problem........
At first, i thought other part of this project might be the cause,
but when I reinstalled and ONLY edited proc.c, and proc.h this hapened...
So I think these two files must be the problem....

Your struct mlfq is missing a semicolon ; after the closing curly brace }. Should be struct mlfq { int limit; struct proc* procs[NPROC]; struct proc* prev; int prev_index; }; . Notice the semicolon on the very end after }

"In my opinion, i think there is some problem with type 'uchar'" -- I concur.  Specifically, I think no definition of that type is in scope at the point where x86.h tries to use it.  That could be either an outright failure to include types.h or a header-order issue.

As a matter of code style that speaks to this, each C source file and header should, at the top, #include all headers needed to provide declarations used in that header or source file (and no others).  To avoid that causing multiple-declaration issues, each header should have include guards to protect its contents against ill effects from multiple inclusion.  As long as you are careful not to produce any circular header dependencies, that will solve / avoid a wide array of header issues.

@JohnBollinger : The missing semicolon will have done it. I looked at xv6's complete console.c and line 15 includes proc.h (with a missing semicolon on a struct) and directly after that includes x86.h . x86.h starts with the definition of inb which gets munged because of the missing semicolon on struct mlfq. That in turn makes it look like inb hasn't been defined causing the implicit declaration error. See: https://github.com/guilleiguaran/xv6/blob/master/console.c

@MichaelPetch, that's certainly an error, but it's not responsible for the specific diagnostics presented in the question.  If the declaration of inb immediately followed that semicolon-less declaration of struct mlfq, and a definition of uchar as a type name were also in scope, then the (first) error would have been for conflicting declarations of uchar.

But it probably explains why there is no diagnostic about declaring uchar with implicit type / without a type specifier.

@JohnBollinger I can tell you this - I pulled the XV6 standard code from Github; made the change with the struct with the missing ; and Those are the exact 2 errors in the OPs question appear (using gcc 11.4.0). When the semicolon is present it builds without either error. They compile with -Wall -Werror .

I also cast a close vote because this is essentially a typo.
